# How can I convert HTML table into PDF with multiple pages for each row of the table

Tags: asp.net-core, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to export HTML table content with 200 rows  into PDF file using jspdf. But each row of the table should be displayed in each page of the pdf file after export. Here is my code . But this code isn't working for multiple records

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function exportToPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {
      '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    doc.fromHTML(
      source,
      15,
      15,
      {
        'width': 180, 
        'elementHandlers': elementHandler
      });

    doc.save('report.pdf');
  }
</script>

<button onclick="exportToPDF()">Export to PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

jspdf has a `addPage` method which can help divide content into pages when convert html to PDF. I have a test with code below and here's the test result.

My cshtml file:

```
<table id="tb1">
    @for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>row + @i + column 1</td>
            <td>row + @i + column 2</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<button onclick="exportToPDF()">Export to PDF</button>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function exportToPDF(){
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var elementHandler = {
              '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
              }
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < $("#tb1 tr").length; i++){
                var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i]
                doc.fromHTML(
                  source,
                  15,
                  15,
                  {
                    'width': 280, 
                    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
                  });
                doc.addPage();
            }
            doc.save('report.pdf');
        }
    </script>
}
```

test result.

[image]